# Why is my function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined

The function validate() is returning undefined, when I expected it to return false or true. Why is this happening? Now I'm just typing this because stackoverflow won't let me post this question, since it is mostly code.

```js
function validate() {
  var isFormValid = false;

  var emailValid = false;
  var inputValid = false;
  var passValid = true;

  //VALIDATE EMAIL
  var emailInput = $("input[type='email']");
  $.get("/checkEmail", {
    email: emailInput.val()
  }, function(data) {
    if (data.userExists) {
      emailInput.removeClass("valid");
      emailInput.addClass("invalid");
      return false;
    } else {
      emailValid = true;
      emailInput.removeClass("invalid");
      emailInput.addClass("valid");
    }

    if (passValid && emailValid && inputValid) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  //ADD VALID CLASS TO INPUTS
  var inputs = $("input,textarea");
  inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      inputValid = true;
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
      $(this).addClass("valid");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("valid");
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
      return false;
    }
    if (passValid && emailValid && inputValid) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  //VADIDATE PASSWORD
  var pass = $("input[name='password']");
  var repass = $("input[name='repassword']");
  if (pass.val() != repass.val()) {
    passValid = false;
    repass.removeClass("valid");
    repass.addClass("invalid");
    return false;
  }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registerForm").submit(function(event) {
    console.log(validate());
    if (!validate()) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: If no condition is matched, nothing is returned so `undefined` is explicitly returned. Also, note that you cannot return from async call.

Comment: How can I solve it then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: @leodaher What is purpose of `javascript` within `validate` following `$.get()` call?

Comment: If you want to do AJAX validation, maybe use the jquery-validate plugin and use its `remote:` method.

Comment: Did you AJAX return something useful?try to open up your dev tool and select the `Network` tab and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Return `$.get()` from `validate`; return `true` or `false` at `.then()` chained to `$.get()` call; use `.then()`, `.fail()` at `.submit()` call to process promise value returned from `.then()` at `validate`

```
function validate() {
  var isFormValid = false;

  var emailValid = false;
  var inputValid = false;
  var passValid = true;

  //VALIDATE EMAIL
  var emailInput = $("input[type='email']");
  // note `return`
  return $.get("/checkEmail", {
    email: emailInput.val()
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // perform all necessary logic, return `true` or `false` within `.then()`
    if (data.userExists) {
      emailInput.removeClass("valid");
      emailInput.addClass("invalid");
      return false;
    } else {
      emailValid = true;
      emailInput.removeClass("invalid");
      emailInput.addClass("valid");
    }

    if (passValid && emailValid && inputValid) {
      return true;
    }
    /*
      // if below logic is necessary, perform logic within `.then()`

      //ADD VALID CLASS TO INPUTS
      var inputs = $("input,textarea");
      inputs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
          inputValid = true;
          $(this).removeClass("invalid");
          $(this).addClass("valid");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("valid");
            $(this).addClass("invalid");
            return false;
        }
        if (passValid && emailValid && inputValid) {
          return true;
        }
     });

     //VADIDATE PASSWORD
     var pass = $("input[name='password']");
     var repass = $("input[name='repassword']");
     if (pass.val() != repass.val()) {
       passValid = false;
       repass.removeClass("valid");
       repass.addClass("invalid");
       return false;
     }
    */
  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registerForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = event.currentTarget;
    validate()
    .then(function(bool) {
      // if `bool` is `true` call `.submit()`
      if (bool) {
        elem.submit()
      }
    })
    // handle error
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(errorThrown)
    })
  });
});
```